# I have an error using group by in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a table 'Clase' with the data:

```
TABLE clase(id_curso int, paralelo char, día int, hora_ini int, duracion int, aula varchar, id_profe int);

insert into clase values(1, 'A', 2, 14, 2,'S-202',4);

insert into clase values(1, 'A', 3, 14, 3,'L-101',4);

insert into clase values(2, 'A', 3, 8, 8,'L-101',5);

insert into clase values(2, 'B', 4, 8, 8,'L-102',5);
```

When I ran:

```
select id_curso, count(distinct paralelo)

from clase

group by id_curso, paralelo

having count(distinct paralelo)>=1
```

I obtain:

```
id_curso || count

1        ||     1

2        ||     1

2        ||     1
```

But I think I should obtain:

```
id_curso || count

1        ||     1

2        ||     2
```

Because the course with the id 2 has two different 'paralelo'.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the paralelo in the group by, otherwise you will always get a value of 1

Comment: Thanks my friend, I was stucked in that question